# How to match a list of bounds with a list of numbers, one-to-one

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization

### The task

I am solving a leetcode style task. Find the amout of values, that can be sortet into a bound (lower <= value <= upper).

Input: first line contains n & m, the amout of bounds and the amount of values.
The second line contains the n lower bounds.
The third line contains the n upper bounds.
The fourth line contains m the values.
(A single bound is li and ri)

Now find the amout of Values, that can be sorted into the bounds, if we do it optimally. (and output it)

Note: Each value can only be assigned one bound and one bound only to one value.

Ex. Input:

```
3 4
1 7 3
4 9 8
5 2 9 2
```

outputs `3`.

### My solution

I have a struct for the bounds:

```
struct Bounds {
    int min, max;
    // operator for sorting both primary and secondary keys
    bool operator < (const Bounds& rhs) const
    {
        if ( min == rhs.min )
            return max > rhs.max;
        else
            return min > rhs.min;
    }
};
```

and solve as follows:

```
int main()
{   
    int n, m, rval = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    Bounds newBound = {0, 0};
    vector<Bounds> bounds(n, newBound);
    vector<int> values(m);

    // get input
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> bounds[i].min;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> bounds[i].max;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cin >> values[i];

    // sort Bounds in descending order by lower bound as primary and upper bound as secondary
    std::sort(bounds.begin(), bounds.end(), less<Bounds>());
    //sort values in ascending order
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), greater<int>());

    // for every bound 
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        int value = values[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < bounds.size(); i++)
        {
            if (bounds[i].min <= value && value <= bounds[i].max) {
                rval++;
                bounds.erase(bounds.begin() + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << rval << "\n";
}
```

### My Problem

This works, but:

1. I don't think this is the optimal solution,
2. It's to slow, as one Testcase with 10^6 values takes ~7 minutes to solve.

How can I improve it? Or should I scrap this approach?

I think my solution has 0(n^2 + (n log(n)))

Or Phrased differently: How can I remove the nested for loop?

Comment: It's confusing that you assume bounds and values are both n. It should be n(bounds) and m(values)

Comment: I don't think that the code works in the first place... it doesn't provide optimal solution for all cases.

Comment: Why should a bound be erased when a value fits in? I don't find a restriction about it.

Comment: The better way is search the bound and check if it's in the correct bound (assuming there is no overlap). So you could reduce `m*n` to `m*log n`.

Comment: Not sure to understand why answer is `3`. `2` (ignore the duplicate?) -> `[1;4]`, `5` -> `[3;8]`, `9` -> `[7;9]`?

Comment: Answer is 3 because ```2 -> [1,4]```,```9 -> [7,9]```and ```5 -> [3,8]```

Comment: The bound is erased, because its a one-to-one relationship, the restriction of one bound to one value applies bidirectionally

Comment: @ALX23z it works, I already solved other subtask with smaller limits of n < 10^4

Comment: o(n^log n): what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because it isn't iterating over the full array, as there are more and more elements deleted, aka. it gets faster with each iteration.

Comment: As written, the question is not intelligible. In particular, "Each value can only be assigned one bound and one bound only to one value." is impossible. Please reproduce the original text.

Comment: I have never met such a complexity. It would correspond to the generation of all tuples of length log n, and there is no reason that this appears in the algorithm. It would be terribly slow (longer than the lifetime of the universe for n=1000).

Comment: Don't forget erase takes O(n-1) in the worse case if you erase the first element.

Comment: @LouisGo Oh damn, didn't know that.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for CodeReview.se, I think.

Comment: Algo seems wrong: for values `5` `10` in ranges `[4; 20]` `[0; 6]`, you place `5` in first range, whereas it should be in second.

Comment: The fact the program finishes the run and gives result doesn't mean it solves the problem.

Comment: This problem is a particular case of the assignment problem, aka bipartite maximum matching, and can be solved using the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). But maybe it is possible to find a more efficient algorithm relying on the "intervals" structure of the bounds?

Comment: Going off the intervals structure of the bounds, I think you could apply a greedy approach by sorting the bounds by start point and the values in ascending order. If there are got N bounds and V values, it should run in O(Nlog(N) + Vlog(V) + V) = O(Nlog(N) + Vlog(V)).